# how to log particular exit code error in particular text file in batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file, logging, xcopy

```
set file=D:\TakeFileName.txt
set staging=D:\Download
echo "File location "'%file%
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=;;" %%A in (%file%) do ( //for loop
 rem   echo  %%A   %%B
 echo f | xcopy %%A %staging%\%%B /C /Q /R /Y 
 echo !errorlevel!
 IF !errorlevel! EQU 0 (echo "0-Successfully file is copied fileName 
 :%%A">0.txt)//logging 0 exitcode error in 0.txt 
 IF !errorlevel! EQU 1  (echo "1-No files were found to copied" >1.txt) 
 IF !errorlevel! EQU 2  (echo "2-User abort operation" >2.txt)
 IF !errorlevel! EQU 4  (echo "4-Initialization error " >4.txt)
 IF !errorlevel! EQU 5  (echo "5- Disk write error occurred." >5.txt)
)
PAUSE
```

This program only log one error in text file ,but i want to log every 0 exit code error in 0.txt suggest how to do it ?

Comment: Just to make you aware that `delims=;;` is effectively the same as `delims=;`. If you have a single **`;`** character elsewhere in the line it will be seen as a delimiter too.

Comment: There are no `//` comments in batch! There is a line-break in the line `IF !errorlevel! EQU 0` which must not be there. Note that the `"` characters are echoed as well in your `echo` commands...

Answer (score 1):

`>` creates a file anew.

`>>` appends to an existing file or creates a new one of the file does not already exist